# Pytorch: calculation precision?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, backpropagation, autograd

I wrote my own autograd using numpy, and I heard pytorch prefers float32 because it's faster and saves memory. so I used float32 in numpy in calculation, and saves in float32 as well.

However, when I compares the result with pytorch, it varies by a bit (for example, the final loss comparison is: numpy autograd:**0.0059468**58786046505 vs pytorch autograd: **0.0059468**69496256113). When I used float64 in numpy, the final result became similar (numpy autograd: **0.953232780278648**1 vs pytorch autograd: **0.953232780278648**4)

So I suspect pytorch calculates everything in float64 but saves its parameters using float32. Is it true? I can't seem to find an answer elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point errors can occur even if two different implementations of the same operation use the same data type the whole way through. If there's any slight difference in implementation, it will often change the result, even if it's just something like changing the order in which some numbers are summed.

For the vast majority of operations, PyTorch does not upcast a float32 to float64. Operations perform calculations using the data types of the inputs, for the best performance. You can try to confirm this by creating a large (thousands of elements) float32 tensor and a large float64 tensor of the same size, and timing how long it takes to run some operation on each of them.

We can also confirm this from the code. Here's a link to part of `torch.prod`'s CPU implementation: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/9f0092c4b7fcc9ca44ac082609ed6c586156d00d/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/ReduceOpsKernel.cpp#L179

The code surrounded by the `AT_DISPATCH_ALL_TYPES_AND_COMPLEX_AND` macro (and others like it, `AT_DISPATCH_*_TYPES*`) gets compiled into multiple different kernels, each with different data types. When `torch.prod` is called with a float32 input, the float32 kernel will be called. When it's called with a float64 input, the float64 kernel will be called. `scalar_t` here will become whatever type it's being compiled for. You can search through PyTorch's codebase and see that these type dispatch macros are used very often.

There may be a few cases where inputs do get upcast or downcast to a different type, but they aren't common. In most cases an operation will either support a particular data type or emit an error if a data type is not supported.